# Clojure :: (String/format "%s" "a") :: fails with ClassCastException

Tags: clojure

The following call:

```
(String/format "%s" "a")
```

... throws a "ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object" exception in Clojure.

```
(String/format "%s" (cast Object "a"))
```

.... produces the same exception.

Comment: Any reason you need to use `String.format` and not [Clojure.core/format](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5162) - it wraps with `to-array` for you? `(format "%s" "a")`

Comment: No reason to use String.format in particular, just being curious ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because last argument in java API is array `Object[]` instead of `Object`.

Just call `(String/format "%s" (into-array ["a"]))`

But more idiomatic to use `(format "Hello %s" "world")`

Answer (score 4):

[L means "I want array" so use `(String/format "%s" (to-array "a"))`. General syntax: `(to-array ["a" 42 0.666]).`

Answer (score 4):

[`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) is using varargs, which are internally plain Java arrays. You then need to convert the input parameters into an array, e.g. by using `to-array`:

```
user=> (String/format "%s" (to-array "a"))
"a"
```